# Router suddenly not resolving previously resolvable hostname

Tags: networking, router, dns

So like 2 hours ago, we suffered an internet outage and when it came back online, the raspberry pi apache server I owned cannot be resolved. However, the even crazier aspect of this is that it managed to resolve before, unlike the other articles on here, who say that they never got it resolved in the first place.

My raspberry pi is named "home-server" precisely and before the outage when I go to http://home-server/ it will work. Now, after the outage when I go there it says DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.
I tried `ipconfig /flushdns` but that didn't work. I also made sure that my all my devices were pointed to DNS `75.75.75.75` with backup as `75.75.76.76`.

All of this had no luck in trying to get the raspberry pi hostname back. I even tried `ssh pi@home-server` and `ping home-server` and it did not work. In the raspberry pi, under `/etc/resolv.conf` here is the contents:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
domain hsd1.va.comcast.net
nameserver 75.75.75.75
nameserver 75.75.76.76
nameserver 2001:558:feed::1
nameserver 2001:558:feed::2
```

I am not sure if that had to do with this, but again, it is udderly strange that this would happen out of nowhere, and what makes it more strange is that it works before, unlike most posts I read on the internet. So now I am stuck because others have said to install avahi but I didn't need avahi or `.local` for it to work beforehand, so what may have caused this to happen? Understanding the cause will help me to find the solution better, and this happened so suddenly I am discombobulated. I have a Xfinity Xfi Modem Cisco DPC3941T, Comcast Subscription if that helps.

Comment: Were you assuming a static IP on the Comcast modem that changed in the outage?  Can you do a soft reset of the Comcast modem or get Comcast to do this. Is it possible to do a soft reset of the Raspberry PI to its settings before the outage?

Comment: The thing is I did not use any static IP which makes it more weird huh. I used DHCP and before the outage it still worked as intended. So I am debating on whether I lucked out before the outage?

Comment: Can you (as I suggested) do soft reset of things. That is what I would do with a hardware router.

Comment: I have reseted the router but no avail

Comment: I don't know for sure. You likely need to reset, set up again, the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I got some more information, it turns out I cannot resolve the hostnames of other PCs as well. So it might have to do with the router.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127867/discussion-between-vjzgaminghd-and-john).